# AWS Advanced Health Reporting shows memory warning - is my Java memory settings to blame?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, heap-memory

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk (T1.small - 1GB RAM) for a Java web app. I've configured it so that the Java Heap has

- min heap 200mb
- max heap 400mb
- max perm-gen 100mb

So in total 500mb reserved for Java 'stuff'.

I felt it was generous leaving 500mb for the operating system and all the other stuff, such as Apache Tomcat.

The problem is, the Elastic Beanstalk advanced health page sometimes starts warning me that I'm using 92% of memory and once it was as high as 96%.  When this happens I tend to bounce the underlying EC2 instance and then the problem is not seen again for days or weeks at a time. I have two instances load balanced and given our current loads it's not being hit very hard.

**Note** I have seen an AWS forum post (which I can't find now) that confirmed that there was a bug in the advanced health reporting, it was miss-reporting the amount of freeMemory and the advice was to turn it off until it was resolved.  I have not found evidence either way to determine if this has been fixed.

I currently don't know what 'memory' is running low, is it the amount of OS memory because 1GB total, memory less 500M Java leaves 500m for everything else and that's sometimes not enough?

I've run my app through a profiler on my local dev machine (Mac with NetBeans) and I do see a sawtooth memory pattern that over hours doesn't look like it's leaking memory.  However, the generations number implies I have objects that a lingering around longer than they should... but given the heap looks healthy, I suspect the surviving objects are very small and probably not a 'leak' persay.

Should I be considering using t1.small (2GB RAM) and then what's the reasonable amount of memory to reserve for non Java stuff?  I'm thinking of reserving 1000M for Heap and 500M for perm gen? Or given that 100M for permgen seems okay with 500M for my current configuation then 1400M for Heap and 100M for Perm Gen.

Also, given that I'm configured to use 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8, then I though PermGen was removed in Java 8?  Or is this still here because it's not the Sun JRE?

Advice on optimising the memory settings would be appreciated, plus tips on verifying that the values are indeed correct.

I include a screenshot of my local development machine, I configured it to use the same min + max and permgen as AWS by configuring tomcat with

-Xms200m -Xmx400m -XX:MaxPermSize=100m

[image: JVM Heap + Garbage Collect on local dev]

My concern with this screenshot is that the surviving generations are increasing, whereas the total memory doesn't really seem to, so it could be a very slow memory leak, or not really one worth worry about.  I'm now going to instrument the classes that have a high survival count and see what's showing up - but given I think this isn't a Java memory problem I only mention this to provide background.

Note at 11:30 I pushed a lot more at the server, this caused an actual *Java* out-of-memory exception, but after the full GC the heap recovered rapidly and everything carried on working fine.  We haven't seen any *Java* OutOfMemory errors on live, probably because we load balance, plus the stress test I was running on my dev machine pushed a lot more images to the server than what we would usually see on live.

Comment: This belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

How much space is being consumed in your swap file? Add that to your numbers.

It is clear that you have memory contention. Add up all of the memory required for the OS, application, frameworks, etc. and then run an instance that has more than the minimum.

I would not design a system that has less than 40% free memory. The OS needs to be able to cache objects, files, etc. When free memory is too low, performance drops significantly.